# blender 2.83.2 viewport Render image color completely different

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, color

System Information
Operating system: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 64 Bits
Graphics card: GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2 NVIDIA Corporation 4.5.0 NVIDIA 451.48

Blender Version
Broken: version: 2.83.2, branch: master, commit date: 2020-07-09 05:50, hash: rB239fbf7d936f
Worked: 2.82 version of Blender that worked as expected

Short description of error
[image]
It's 2.83.2 version viewport render.
[image]
It's 2.82 version viewport render.
2.83 version has
The viewport image render result color is completely different compared to the viewport.
I tested in blender 2.9 alpha. the result is same.
Maybe Revamped color management update is cause.
How can I fix this mismatch?
Is it impossible because of technical problems?

Exact steps for others to reproduce the error

1. In viewport shading mode.
2. Click Viewport Render Image.
   3.Compare result color
3. If It's hard to see. Tweak Exposure and Gamma and redo Viewport Render Image.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.blender.org/T77909

It's a bug at blender 2.83 may fix it blender 2.9